# Angular проблема при старте (начало проекта)

Tags: javascript, angular

Всем привет, помогите в вопросе, не могу понять почему не запускается хост. делал все по инструкции. пишет что не может найти файл, хотя по факту он есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что в декораторе @Component? Он там указан?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin да. добавил скрин

Comment: Ошибка в самом файле css. Покажите что там

Comment: @EzioMercer Добавил скрин, файл пустой

Comment: Такс, удалите все эти файлы, создайте компоненту с помощью команды angular (`ng-component` если не ошибаюсь) и посмотрите будет ли ошибка

Comment: @EzioMercer так я их не создавал, их сам ангуляр создал, я проделал точно так же на другом пк, все работает, на этом нет

Comment: Ну не знаю, тогда.... Попробуйте создать с нуля ещё один проект

Comment: @EzioMercer вы думаете такое я не пробовал делать?) тут что-то с системой я так думаю не так, но что именно я не могу понять

Comment: @СергейСнегирев Ну у меня такое было однажды с React-ом, я просто снёс и с нуля создал, после этого заработало

Answer (score 1):

ошибка была в названии папки, везде где было написано C#, он не создавал проект, создал на рабочем столе папку JS и в ней проект создался